# Making a new line when a number is reached

Tags: java

A question has asked me to create a loop that will count in 3s up to 300. I am able to get that part but it then asks when it reaches 30, I must create a new line and then add 30 again so it will be come 60 and then a new line will be created again.

This is my code so far:

```
int x;
int z = 30;

for (x = 3; x <= 300; x = x + 3 ) {
    System.out.print(" " + x);

    if (x == z) {
        System.out.println("");

        z = z + 30;
    }
}
```

Here is the output:

```
3 6 9 12 15 18 21 24 27 30
33 36 39 42 45 48 51 54 57 60
63 66 69 72 75 78 81 84 87 90
93 96 99 102 105 108 111 114 117 120
123 126 129 132 135 138 141 144 147 150
153 156 159 162 165 168 171 174 177 180
183 186 189 192 195 198 201 204 207 210
213 216 219 222 225 228 231 234 237 240
243 246 249 252 255 258 261 264 267 270
273 276 279 282 285 288 291 294 297 300
```

Comment: @Lotharyx Your point? He's asking about a specific problem.

Comment: Why has this got so many downvotes? Stackoverflow should welcome new programmers, not try scare them off. I see this a lot in the community, questions which programmers deem _easy_ they tend to downvote, just because its easy to you it may not be to others, **everyone** starts somewhere.

Comment: @PorkStew could you please edit your question and add a specific question you're requesting help with?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
if ((x % 30) == 0) { System.out.println(); }
```

Comment: Why 90? Should it not be 30?

Comment: I thought you wanted 30 items displayed and then create a new line.
If you want every thirtieth value, then change it to 30 and you can drop `z`.

Comment: He wants a new line every time 30 has been added to the count.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
Your code fixed the problem: I just had to changed the 90 to 30 and it worked.

Comment: Sorry @PorkStew but what fixed what? The code posted from PorkStew produce the output he wrote. The code posted from Grayson applied to the code posted from PorkStew produce the same output. I'm a bit confused.

Comment: The problem i was have was that it would not make a new line when it reached the number 30, 60, 90 and so on till 300. i fixed the problem with Grayson code.

Comment: Maybe I'm very tired but what I see is that the code in your post already do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You should honestly, be using indexes and multiplying them by the step to determine when to start and end your loop.

This is easier to understand, and easier to follow.

```
public class NumberPrinter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printNumbers(1, 100, 3, 10);
    }

    static void printNumbers(int startIndex, int endIndex, int step, int linelimit) {
        int start = step * startIndex;
        int end   = step * endIndex;
        int mod   = step * linelimit;

        while (start <= end) {
            System.out.printf(" %3d", start);

            if ((start % mod) == 0) {
                System.out.println();
            }

            start += step;
        }
    }
}
```